# Strange Behavior With Streamsets SQL Server Change Tracking Origin

Tags: streamsets

I am trying to use the SQL Change Tracking Origin to Create data ingestion pipeline. I have connected the origin and specified all the neccessary jdbc parameters and the pipeline validates successfully. However on running the pipeline, I get the following exception in the logs

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '13'.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:137)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2348)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2320)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.JdbcBaseRunnable.getOrLoadTableReadContext(JdbcBaseRunnable.java:432)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.JdbcBaseRunnable.generateBatchAndCommitOffset(JdbcBaseRunnable.java:217)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.JdbcBaseRunnable.run(JdbcBaseRunnable.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:227)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:223)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeRunnable.run(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:227)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:33)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:223)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeRunnable.run(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '13'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:284)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementProxy.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariPreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(HikariPreparedStatementProxy.java)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.TableReadContext.<init>(TableReadContext.java:66)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.TableReadContext.<init>(TableReadContext.java:50)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.cache.SQLServerCTContextLoader.load(SQLServerCTContextLoader.java:73)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.jdbc.multithread.cache.SQLServerCTContextLoader.load(SQLServerCTContextLoader.java:32)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
    ... 29 more
```

Under closer observation, I saw that the query being sent to SQL Server was wrong

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.tbl_transactions, 612546687) AS CT 
WHERE (CT.transaction_id > 796867843 
AND CT.req_datetime > 2018-06-07 13:44:29.707 
AND (CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION = 612546771 ) OR (CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION > 612546771 ) )
ORDER BY SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, CT.transaction_id, CT.req_datetime TableReadContext
```

as against

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.tbl_transactions, 612546687) AS CT 
WHERE (CT.transaction_id > 796867843 
AND CT.req_datetime > '2018-06-07 13:44:29.707' 
AND (CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION = 612546771 ) OR (CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION > 612546771 ) )
ORDER BY SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, CT.transaction_id, CT.req_datetime TableReadContext
```

The problem being that the parameter is not quoted. Please can Anyone Direct me on what I am doing wrong or how i can mitigate against this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug - we created [SDC-9200](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-9200) to track it.